# Trying to make a div appear when hovering over an image.. cannot get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, animation, hover

So I'm trying to make a textbox div appear when I hover over an image, it doesn't seem to work. 
Related code will be put beneath, thanks for all help!

```css
 .prisoner-info-div{
        height:75px;
        width:500px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    #poison-ivy-info{
        top:450px;
        left:200px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #joker-info{
        top:450px;
        left:200px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #riddler-info{
        bottom:75px;
        left:200px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #penguin-info{
        bottom:75px;
        left:200px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #harley-quinn-info{
        bottom:75px;
        left:200px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #poison-ivy-door:hover  #poison-ivy-info{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #joker-door:hover  #joker-info{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #riddler-door:hover  riddler-info{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #penguin-door:hover  #penguin-info{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #harley-quinn-door:hover  #harley-quinn-info{
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<div class="prison" id="poison-ivy"> <img class="prisoners"src="images/poison-ivy.png" alt="poison-ivy"> <img class="door" id="poison-ivy-door"src="images/door.png" alt="prison-dppr"> </div>
        <div id="poison-ivy-info" class="prisoner-info-div">Poison Ivy is depicted as one of the world's most prominent eco-terrorists. She is obsessed with plants, botany, and environmentalism. She uses toxins from plants and her own bloodstream for her criminal activities</div>
        
        <div class="prison" id="joker"> <img class="prisoners"src="images/joker.png" alt="joker"> <img class="door" id="joker-door"src="images/door.png" alt="prison-door"> </div>
        <div id="joker-info" class="prisoner-info-div">The Joker is a master criminal with a clown-like appearance, and is considered one of the most infamous criminals within Gotham City.</div>
        
        <div class="prison" id="riddler"> <img class="prisoners"src="images/riddler.png" alt="riddler"> <img class="door" id="riddler-door"src="images/door.png" alt="prison-door"> </div>
        <div id="riddler-info" class="prisoner-info-div">The Riddler has an obsession with riddles, puzzles, and word games. The character frequently delights in over-stating his "intellectual superiority" and on forewarning both Batman and the police of his capers by sending them complex clues.</div>
        
        <div class="prison" id="penguin"> <img class="prisoners"src="images/penguin.png" alt="penguin"> <img class="door" id="penguin-door"src="images/door.png" alt="prison-door"> </div>
        <div id="penguin-info" class="prisoner-info-div">The Penguin is a Gotham City mobster who fancies himself a "gentleman of crime", often wearing a monocle, top hat, and tuxedo. The character is a short, obese man with a long nose, and he uses high-tech umbrellas as weapons.</div>
        
        <div class="prison" id="harley-quinn"> <img class="prisoners"src="images/harley-quinn.png" alt="hayley-quinn"> <img class="door" id="harley-quinn-door"src="images/door.png" alt="prison-door"> </div>
        <div id="harley-quinn-info" class="prisoner-info-div">Harley Quinn is a frequent accomplice and lover of the Joker, whom she met while working as an intern psychiatrist at Gotham City's Arkham Asylum, where the Joker was a patient.</div>
```

The info divs are what I'm trying to make a appear when hovering over the "doors".

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can Target element siblings and children. The problem here is you're trying to target an element that is outside of that context.

You'll need to use the image's parent DIV as the `hover`able class, and then use a `+` to target the sibling div which you'd like to appear.

```
.image-container:hover + .div-to-appear {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write down this code for target text div on hover image

```
.prison:hover + .prisoner-info-div{visibility: visible;}
```